# How to remove from list every duplicate Value in certain part of list?

Tags: c#, list, distinct

I got an List which got Data from an class, that has this propertys:

```
  public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }
    public string Teil { get; set; }
    public decimal Preis { get; set; }
```

after I added Data to this list I have the Problem that in Column "Teil" a lot of duplicates are.

I want to remove every duplicate from "Teil" and when its removing it should remove the whole row with "Preis" and "ExtraInfo" from this row.

Normally I would think of distinct but that seems just to delete If the full row has an duplicate.

**List example:**

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghl4I.png)

Does anyone got an Idea or an tip how to achieve this?

Comment: What happens if two objects have the same `Teil` property value but different `Preis` and `ExtraInfo` property values? Which one remains?

Comment: If Teil is an duplicate, then Preis and ExtraInfo could be different but if Teil is dusplicate It should remove the full row

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Please [edit] your post with an example input list and the expected output. If you've attempted something, please include that with the actual behavior.

Comment: thats not Import which remains, importend is that Teil got no duplicates

Comment: Related: [LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property).

Comment: The first duplicate value that is found  should get removed

Comment: If you're using .NET6 or higher, you can use the [`DistinctBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-7.0) linq method:

`var distinctList = list.DistinctBy(x => x.Teil);`

Comment: @ambroise.la the problem with that is it's dependent on the ordering of your list for which object remains when the non-selected properties are different.

Comment: @gunr2171 You're right but in that particular case I don't think it's an issue (comment from author: "thats not Import which remains, importend is that Teil got no duplicates").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DistinctBy` method of type `List`. (Check [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-7.0)). It will apply `Distinct` method only based on `Teil` attribute.

```
List<Data> examples = new()
{
    new Data { ExtraInfo = "InfoA", Teil = "TeilA", Preis = 0 },
    new Data { ExtraInfo = "InfoA", Teil = "TeilA", Preis = 0 },
    new Data { ExtraInfo = "InfoA", Teil = "TeilB", Preis = 0 },
    new Data { ExtraInfo = "InfoA", Teil = "TeilA", Preis = 0 },
};

var result = examples.DistinctBy(data => data.Teil).ToList();
result.ForEach(res => Console.WriteLine($"ExtraInfo: {res.ExtraInfo}, Teil: {res.Teil}, Preis: {res.Preis}"));
// Output result :
// ExtraInfo: InfoA, Teil: TeilA, Preis: 0
// ExtraInfo: InfoA, Teil: TeilB, Preis: 0
```